# In Google Apps Script, avoid second 'Review Permissions' prompt, possibly by using approval_prompt

Tags: google-apps-script

I have searched StackOverflow, etc. for a solution to this problem, and several answers 'point me in a direction' (mentioning approval_prompt = auto not approval_prompt = force), but none are applicable (as far as I can tell) to my situation.

I have a Web Application hosted at www.mjpanel.com that expects to use a Google Apps Script that I 'own', but the Javascript at www.mjpanel.com calls the Google Apps Script (deployed as a Web App with doGet()) as a Web Service.  It expects the web service call to return various JSON objects.

If the user has not yet authorized my application, the call to the Google Apps Script Web App / Web Service will not return a JSON object, causing www.mjpanel.com Javascript code to fail saying "Invalid Request" (because it isn't a JSON object as my code expects).

To prevent this from happening, www.mjpanel.com uses gapi.auth2.init to get the permissions/scopes it needs.  I'm developing everything now, so if/whenever the Google Apps Script evolve to use something (like sending GMail emails as the user) that is new, I have been figuring out the scope to request, adding it to the list of scopes in the gapi.auth2.init call, and everything is fine.  The next time a user uses the app., they get initially prompted for the newly added scope, then everything proceeds fine.

However, now sometimes one of my test users has a Web Service call fail because Google Apps Script is returning another request for permissions for a 'new permission' of 'Have Offline Access'.

There's nothing about my script that would warrant the user needing to grant this permission.

When I research, a lot of stuff (mostly about requesting OAuth2 stuff in a 'structure' different than the way my app. is set up) says it has to do with submitting a 'approval_prompt=force' in my request URL.

However, the way I have my app set up, all the URLs I would use (aside from my 'custom stuff' in the query string) are dictated by Google Apps Script.  And I can't find any place where any URL I use has an approval_prompt in it.

I can't figure out where I would need to configure that approval_prompt to be auto (as is recommended in the 'successful answers' I find).

Of if the idea of approval_prompt is 'on the wrong track', any information in general to help me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Google Apps Script native OAuth flow includes `approval_prompt=force`. This causes the following conditions:

- If cookie exists in browser and has permission for this application the consent screen will not be displayed.
- If cookie exists in browser but does not have permission for this application: consent screen will be displayed
- If cookie does not exist in browser and the application has permissions: application will request 'Have offline access'.

The easiest way around this is to manage your own OAuth flow and use the Execution API. The following link will take you to the javascript quick start.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/target-script